# Unable to get a range scale function working

Tags: r, range, max, min, scaling

I'm trying to apply the range scaling formula on across columns of a dataset.
The [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) I'm using is the Mean Normalisation of the available methods for range scaling.

[image: formula]

I've currently tried using the following code:

```
rangescale <- function(r){
  colmean <- apply(r,2,mean)
  colsd <- apply(r, 2, sd)
  cv <- sweep(r, 2, colmean, "-")
  xmax <- apply(r, 2, max)
  xmin <- apply(r,2, min)
  ma.mi <- apply(xmax, 2, xmin, "-")
  rv <- sweep(cv, 2, ma.mi, "/")
  return(rv)
}
```

It is giving me:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'xmin' of mode 'function' was not found
```

It doesn't look like that base r has the minimum function, are there other methods to get the min and max of columns? Or are there problems I've missed out entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function to apply scaling

```
rangescale <- function(x) (x  - mean(x))/(max(x) - min(x))
```

and apply it column-wise

```
apply(r, 2, rangescale)
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
r %>% summarise_all(rangescale)
```

---

To pass entire dataset to the function we can take `apply` inside the function

```
rangescale <- function(r) {
  apply(r, 2, function(x) (x  - mean(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
}
```

and then call it as :

```
r1 <- rangescale(r)
```

Comment: for the ```apply(r,2,rangescale)```, am I suppose to assign it to another variable if I would like to use it as ```rangescale(x)``` (x being the dataset)?

Comment: @strkiky2 Updated the answer so you can now pass the entire dataset in the function.

Comment: The r1 wasn't needed, but ```function(x)``` inside ```apply``` worked wonderfully, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may not matter much in your current use case, but I leave it here for posterity:

You could make it a bit more efficient using the `matrixStats` package (useful for large matrices):

```r
library(matrixStats)
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
n.col = 1000
n.row = 120
my.matrix <- matrix(rnorm(n.row * n.col), nrow = n.row)

rangescale1 <- function(x){
    cr <- colRanges(x)
    t((t(x) - colMeans(x))/(cr[,2] - cr[,1]))
}

rangescale2 <- function(r) {
    apply(r, 2, function(x) (x  - mean(x))/(max(x) - min(x)))
}

microbenchmark(
    rangescale1(my.matrix),
    rangescale2(my.matrix)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                    expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq
#>  rangescale1(my.matrix)  823.150  854.3335 1135.847  900.5095  981.5745
#>  rangescale2(my.matrix) 5564.432 5787.9025 6717.374 5905.3510 6687.6110
#>        max neval cld
#>   5689.234   100  a 
#>  21350.869   100   b

all.equal(rangescale1(my.matrix), rangescale2(my.matrix))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>